# in angular 4 service .map function did not wok

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm beginner to angular 7.I'm using angular 7 to create some app. in service i'm imported map but it did not work. how can i resolve it? here is the code of service file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()

export class DataService {
    users: string[];
    data: Observable<Array<number>>;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.users = ['supun' , 'madhushi' , 'kennady' , 'sachini'];
    }

    getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    getUsers1() {
        return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    getData() {
        this.data = new Observable(observer => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                observer.next(1);
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                observer.next(2);
            }, 2000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                observer.next(3);
            }, 3000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                observer.next('hello');
            }, 4000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                observer.complete();
            }, 5000);

        });

        return this.data;
    }
}
```

error is this.http.get(...).map is not a function

Comment: What version of angular are you using? http is deprecated, you should use HttpClientModule and HttpClient instead.

Comment: You're mixing an obsolete version of Angular, using a deprecated Http service, with a newer version of RxJS, while still using the older RxJS syntax. Do yourself a favor, and restart from scratch, by reading the documentation of the latest stable Angular version, and using the documented HttpClient.

Comment: @FRECIA these are the version that are in package,json "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"

Comment: @JBNizet thank you i will read the documentation.

Comment: You can use HttpClientModule  instead of using HttpModule. you are not using angular 4 but it is angular 7.:)

Comment: @Asanka after addding this i saw what is the version of angular. :) i have used HttpClientModule. but map function did not work,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to see pipe, as you are using RxJS latest version.

```
return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .pipe(
       map(res => res.json())
    );
```

Comment: Now it's work. thank you. Can you tell what is the use of pipe?

Comment: Before Rxjs 5.5, every operators and Observable functions are assigned to prototype, which will increase the bundle size. As part of Rxjs 5.5, They wrote a complete RxJS rewrite by introducing pipe operators, Which will accept observable as input and emit Observable as output. It also allows to chain the Observable

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm just new to angular.

Answer (score 1):

`this.http.get` will return an Observable. You cannot do a `map` to an observable. You need to `.subscribe` to the observable, convert the result to JSON and then do a `.map` on it.

Example :
`this.http.get('url').subscribe(res => res.json()).map(x => {
// do something with x
});`